# macOS/bash equivalent of mv -t

Tags: osx, mv

I am using macOS and trying to execute the following commands in Bash:

```
cd root  ||  exit
shopt -s dotglob
for d in ./*
do
        if [ -d "$d" ]
        then
                find "$d" -type f -exec mv -i -t "$d" {} +
                find "$d" -mindepth 1 -type d -delete
        fi
done
```

The `mv` command in macOS does not allow `-t` flag to specify directory and gives the following error:

```
mv: illegal option --t
usage: mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source target
```

How to do this in macOS?

Comment: @Jesse recursive, so all files in subdirectories get moved too. It seems they're flattening all subdirectories.

Comment: On macOS, you would install coreutils using e.g. Homebrew, then use `gmv` with the same options as with `mv` on Linux.  Either that, or rewrite the code to use a simple loop, or slightly tweak the `find` command's `-exec`.

Comment: @Jesse_b `-exec ... {} +`, the `{} +` must appear exactly like that, with no stuff in-between. `-exec ... {} ... \;` would work though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without `-t`, you have to keep the target directory as the last non-option argument to `mv`. That gives us two options: either have `find` put the filename before the target directory for `mv`, or find something else that can do the same thing. 
So, either:

```
find "$d" -type f -exec mv -i {} "$d" \;
```

Or:

```
export d; find "$d" -type f -exec sh -c 'exec mv -i "$@" "$d"' sh {} +
```

In the first command, `mv` is executed for each file. In the second, `sh -c ...` is executed for a batch of files, and that in turn runs `mv` for the entire batch. The second option can be much faster, but since you're using interactive confirmation, it won't matter much.

Answer (score 1):

it has nothing to do with bash. It is the `mv` command.

You can install gnu `mv`, to get the `-t` option. Alternatively see other answers, but with this one extra bit of advice.

The man page shows these two modes ( I removed the `-t` mode)

```
mv [OPTION]... [-T] SOURCE DEST
mv [OPTION]... SOURCE... DIRECTORY
```

You may notice that if you don't specify the `-T` (also, I think, only in Gnu mv), and have two arguments, then the grammar is ambiguous. The ambiguity is resolved by examining the last file. If it is a directory, then it is the 2nd form, else it is the 1st form. The grammar can be made un-ambiguous by putting a `/` after the directory name, thus forcing the 2nd form. This will stop many errors. Unfortunately the only way to dis-disambiguate the 1st form is with the `-T`.